# How to get the MIME type of a file in Qt?

Tags: qt, mime

Is there a way to get the MIME type of a file in Qt?

I am writing an application that needs to find the MIME type of a given file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use 3rd party libraries for this purpose, there is no mime-type guessing support in Qt itself.  On Linux/Unix you could use libmagic.

Comment: Perfect - that did exactly what I was hoping for.

Comment: This is no longer true.  Qt now offers mime type lookups.

Answer (score 35):

Qt 5 has added support for MIME types:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimedatabase.html

```
QString path("/home/my_user/my_file");
#if QT_VERSION >= QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 0, 0)
    QMimeDatabase db;
    QMimeType type = db.mimeTypeForFile(path);
    qDebug() << "Mime type:" << type.name();
#endif
```

See also: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmimetype.html

Comment: Qt5 package can be quite easily backported to Qt4. Just compile all the files under mimetypes and standardpaths from the Qt5 source into a library or along with your application. Some modifications need to be made if the sources are taken from Qt 5.5+ I believe.

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <QMimeDatabase>  

QString mimeType( const QString &filePath ){ return QMimeDatabase().mimeTypeForFile( filePath ).name(); }
```

Comment: QString mime = QMimeDatabase().mimeTypeForFile(path).name();

Comment: Or, encapsulate the implementation details as I have in this function.